# Python Tensorflow Dataset Filter Set .issubset()

Tags: python, tensorflow, set, tensorflow-datasets

I have a tensorflow dataset:

```
def fake_sequence():
    seq = [np.random.choice(["A", "B", "C", "D"]) for _ in range(100)]
    mutate = [np.random.choice(["E", "F", "G", "H"]) for _ in range(100)]
    mask = np.random.choice(a=[True, False], size=100, p=[0.999, 0.001])
    return "".join(np.where(mask, seq, mutate))


seqs = [fake_sequence() for _ in range(100)]
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(seqs)
```

I'd like to filter it with the following pythonic function:

```
def python_filter(x):
   x = set(x)
   x = x.issubset({"A", "B", "C", "D"})
   return x
```

Unfortunately, decorating with `@tf.function` doesn't work. Can any of you wizards help me? Here's what I have so far.

```
def filter(x):
    x = tf.strings.bytes_split(x)
    x = tf.unique(x)[0]
    # tensorflow function for x.issubset({"A", "B", "C", "D"})
    return x

ds = ds.filter(filter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `tf.lookup.StaticHashTable` and `tf.cond` to solve what you want:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def fake_sequence():
    seq = [np.random.choice(["A", "B", "C", "D"]) for _ in range(100)]
    mutate = [np.random.choice(["E", "F", "G", "H"]) for _ in range(100)]
    mask = np.random.choice(a=[True, False], size=100, p=[0.999, 0.001])
    return "".join(np.where(mask, seq, mutate))


seqs = [fake_sequence() for _ in range(100)]
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(seqs)

keys_tensor = tf.constant(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'])
vals_tensor = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys_tensor, vals_tensor),
    default_value=-1)

def filter(x):
    subset = tf.constant(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
    x = tf.strings.bytes_split(x)
    x = tf.unique(x)[0]
    x, y = tf.sort(table.lookup(x)), tf.sort(table.lookup(subset))
    return tf.cond(tf.shape(x)[0]>tf.shape(y)[0], lambda: False, lambda: tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(x, y)))

ds = ds.map(filter)
for x in ds.take(5):
  print(x)
```

The `tf.lookup.StaticHashTable` just maps all letters to integer values, which are easier to compare.

Comment: Note: if you don't know the random non-subset values, use ```KeyValueTensorInitializer(tf.constant([chr(i) for i in range(128)]), range(128))```, but I'm sad there's not a cleaner solution :(

Comment: Also, can the last line if ```filter()``` be replaced with ```tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(x, y))``` since sort() will make all numeric values the same?

Comment: You mean you wanna leave out the first part of the condition? The first part is necessary because x and y are not always the same length.. try it out.